# -[NSString sizeWithFont:] only takes into account the font I'm passing in, not fallback fonts for Japanese characters

Tags: ios, localization, sizewithfont

I'm passing some strings into -[NSString sizeWithFont:]. These strings have both Western and Japanese characters.

The only way these strings can be displayed are with two fonts: the Western font I'm using, and a Japanese font that is used as a fallback because those characters aren't present in the Western font.

The problem: it *seems* like -[NSString sizeWithFont:] isn't ever taking into consideration the Japanese font, just the Western font that I'm passing in. And that makes calculating the size of these strings tricky at best.

Does anyone know how to handle this situation?

Comment: is it possible for you to create two temp strings, one string for the western and one string for the japanese characters, and then size them independently and combine the result? I realize that with kerning this probably won't work super well...

Comment: Well, possibly...but I don't even know what Japanese font it's falling back to! Is there a way to tell?